# .Net 4.0 Caching Data in SqlServer Database Rather In memory Caching

Tags: asp.net, .net, caching

I know that Microsoft has given System.Runtime.Caching name space in .net 4.0 framework. This helps us very good in terms of In Memory Caching data ( by using MemoryCache class). But Like enterprise library, it supports the Data Base Caching as well. I need to know that how to do my data caching (just to put and pic data) in sqlserver db, using the new feature introduced by microsoft. I have gone through, but could not find any article which gives any example through code. Please if any one know let me know.

More over if some body can suggest a db model for this in example.

Answer (score 1):

Its more a question of where you need this data and how often you'd have to go to an "expensive" resource to get it.

For instance if you have data from a 3rd party site, you could 'cache' that data within your own database, giving you much faster access to it.

If you have data from your own database, that is "expensive" to produce or process, you could also cache that data in memory on your web tier.

Comment: Yes, I understand it is expensive and in my scenario it may not be practical. But I still want to know how to work with Sql DataBase caching using .net framework 4.0 (System.Runtime.Caching). If please you can demonstrate any thing for this?